# Finding Laurent Series of a function

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

I've been assigned to write a computer program which then calculates the Laurent series of a function. Of course I'm familiar with the concept, but I've always calculated the Laurent series in an ad hoc way using Taylor series, never used an algorithmic method. I'd be grateful if someone helps me in finding an algorithm to produce the Laurent series using the inputs mentioned in the question below :-)

```
Given a fractional function containing polynomials in both numerator
and denominator; find its Laurent series in all convergence domains.
The polynomials are given by its zeros. For example, the function 
((z-1)(z+i))/(z^2(z-1)(z+1)) is given in the input as:
+   1+0i    0-1i 
    0+0i    0+0i    1+0i    -1+0i 
The first sign (+ or -) defines the sign of the fraction. 
The output of the above example is the Laurent series around z0=0 in two convergence domains: |z|<1 and |z|>1.
```

Comment: This is really just partial fraction decomposition, which is Lagrange interpolation in disguise. The tricky issue is repeated roots. Have a look here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition

the general result is here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition#General_result

Comment: @AlexR. Well I've not implemented the general approach but when using for example SymPy library for symbolical computations in a language like Python it produces 1.0*(z + I)/(z**2*(1.0*z + 1.0)) as a result of decomposing the above function :(

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean? Are you saying you're not sure how to find the partial fraction expansion of this polynomial?

Comment: @AlexR. Yes that's what I mean. We have (1+0i) in both numerator and denominator. Should I omit it or consider it? Is it correct to evaluate the Taylor series for 1/(z+1) and 1/(z-1) then multiply the result to 1/z^2 and the numerator?

Comment: The same roots on numerator and denominator can be cancelled as they form a removable singularity. It would be correct to do what you're saying if you want a Laurent series around 0